# change sql parameter to date decimal

Tags: sql, database, crystal-reports, db2

I have a SQL command in crystal reports (its OK if your not familiar with crystal) and I need to convert a date parameter to a decimal (to match a column in the database.)

```
SELECT decimaldate FROM TABLE1 WHERE decimaldate = {?normaldate} 
--ex: 12/01/2011 needs to become 12012011
```

IF I use a CAST on the above query it doesn't work:

```
SELECT decimaldate FROM TABLE1 WHERE decimaldate =
 CAST(CAST{?normaldate} AS VARCHAR) AS DECIMAL)
```

Comment: Its in crystal, and crystal uses SQL, even though the datasource is DB2

Comment: Does DB2 have a `DatePart` function?

Comment: Possibly, but I am using SQL in Crystal, so would I have to use DB2 commands?

Comment: @user719825: How is decimaldate being stored in the database? Is it time elapsed since an epoch date (similar to a Unix datestamp), an 8-digit transliteration of a conventional date (such as 20121220 for today) or some other way?

Comment: We would also require knowledge of how your decimal type represents a date?  For example, would `0.0` represent `01-01-1970 00:00:00.000` and `0.5` represent `01-01-1970 12:00:00.000`?  Without knowing the encoding method, we can't be sure to give you an accurate answer.  [This para-phrases @MarkBannister who also just asked a similar question.]

Comment: It is stored as 20121220 as in your example.

Comment: everything is stored as an 8 digit date without the slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
 select CAST(replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 101), '/', '') AS DECIMAL)
```

Or something like this where @normaldate is the search date.

```
SELECT decimaldate FROM TABLE1 WHERE decimaldate = CAST(replace(convert(varchar, @normaldate, 101), '/', '') AS DECIMAL)
```

Comment: I get an error: End OF statement not valid. Should it be something other then 101?

Comment: That works in SQL Server but not sure if it translates correct in crystal reports. 101 is a valid data format. http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: Try this -> select convert(varchar, getdate(), 101).  If that works, it doesn't like the replace statement.

Comment: It should be {?normaldate} instead of {@normaldate}.  Make sure to create the parameter in the Command object too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a formula (called something like @decimaldate) in formula to hold the equivalent numeric value of your date paramter - so it would be something like:

```
year({?normaldate})*10000 + month({?normaldate})*100 + day({?normaldate})
```

- then amend your selection criteria to select based on your new formula - like so:

```
SELECT decimaldate FROM TABLE1 WHERE decimaldate = {@decimaldate}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [`VARCHAR_FORMAT()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html) is actually what you're looking for:

```
SELECT decimaldate
  FROM table1
 WHERE decimaldate = VARCHAR_FORMAT(@NormalDate, 'MMDDYYY')
```

You may have to wrap `@NormalDate` with `DATE()` to cast it to a date type (it depends on your input format).

Comment: That's a good function to use. Depending on the data type of the decimaldate column, you may also need to cast the output of the VARCHAR_FORMAT() call to a DECIMAL type.

Answer (score 0):

This DB2 SQL function performs the date to MDY decimal conversion your query needs. Once it's created, your queries can compare a decimal column containing an MDY date to the output of UTIL.TO_DECIMAL_MDY( someValidDate )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION util.to_decimal_mdy(dateval DATE)
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURNS DECIMAL(9,0)
RETURN MONTH(dateval) * 10000000 + DAY(dateval) * 100000 + YEAR(dateval)
;
```