# Convert DB2 SQL Decimal to DATE

Tags: sql, database, db2, decimal

I need to convert Decimal to date. I have a decimal date field that contains data like this :

- 1,132,009.00    --1/13/2009
- 7,152,004.00   --7/15/2004
- 11,012,005.00   --11/01/2005

  etc

I would like it to read as **xx/xx/xxxx**.

Is there anyway to do this with SQL commands or DB2 logic in a select statement?

```
SELECT  column1  from  table1  ;
```

Comment: What dates does each one of these map to? I can't see any meaning in those numbers

Comment: possible duplicate of [change sql parameter to date decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578252/change-sql-parameter-to-date-decimal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH x(decvalue) AS ( VALUES (DECIMAL(1132009.00)),(DECIMAL(7152004.00)),(DECIMAL(11012005.00)) )

SELECT CAST( 
    LPAD( RTRIM( CHAR( INTEGER( decvalue/1000000 ))), 2, '0' ) || '/' || 
    LPAD( RTRIM( CHAR( MOD( decvalue/10000, 100 ))), 2, '0' )  || '/' ||
    MOD( decvalue, 10000 ) 
AS CHAR(10)) 
AS chardateresult
FROM x
;
```

Comment: I wrote it as a standalone SQL statement so it can be executed as-is in any DB2 database, without creating any objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same `WITH` values as @Fred, I came up with:

```
WITH x(decvalue) AS ( VALUES (DECIMAL(1132009.00)),(DECIMAL(7152004.00)),(DECIMAL(11012005.00)) )

SELECT TO_DATE(CHAR(CAST(decvalue AS DECIMAL(8,0))), 'MMDDYYYY')
FROM x
```

This assumes that your input values aren't going to be longer than 8 digits (2 for month, 2 for day, 4 for year), otherwise you'll get an overflow error on the cast.  It will also fail if there's not at least some value for each of month, day, and year (`00002011` would not work, for example, but `01012011` would).

Comment: This didn't work for me until I trimmed the trailing spaces off of the string with RTRIM(), and then used LPAD() to ensure that seven-digit date strings are padded with a leading zero. WITH x(decvalue) AS ( VALUES (DECIMAL(1132009.00)),(DECIMAL(7152004.00)),(DECIMAL(11012005.00)) )

SELECT TO_DATE(
LPAD(
    RTRIM(CHAR(CAST(decvalue AS DECIMAL(8,0)))),
    8,'0'
), 
'MMDDYYYY')
FROM x

Comment: Strange, it worked fine as I have it.  I tested it on LUW 9.7.  Perhaps you're on a different platform that handles things slightly different?  (Also, I seem to be running into you a lot today, Fred.  :-) )

Comment: Weird. I don't know what might be causing that. I'm running DB2 9.7 Fix Pack 5 (s111017) on 64-bit Windows, and when I paste your statement in and try to run it, I get SQL20448N because the format string is 'MMDDYYYY', and the input string is '1132009   '
Would you happen to have Oracle compatibility enabled for the database you're using? Either way, it's good to have more DB2 LUW folks hanging around here.

Comment: Nope, no Oracle compatibility mode as far as I know (there would be no reason to enable it, we've always been a DB2 shop).  I also get the same results when I try it on our z/OS DB2.  We're on Linux 64-bit, and I see no `DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR` in `SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.REG_VARIABLES`