# convert decimal to date during where clause

Tags: sql, database, datetime, db2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert DB2 SQL Decimal to DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580956/convert-db2-sql-decimal-to-date)

I have a db2 database and I want to convert a decimal to a date during the where clause in a select statement.

The decimal date *could* be 12 or 13 characters long depending on the month.

**12 characters:**

***1***,241,999.00 should become: 1999/***1***/24

**13 Characters:**

***12***,241,999.00 should become: 1999/***12***/24

The column name is DECIMALCOLUMN:

```
Select * from table1 WHERE
cast(replace(convert,DECIMALCOLUMN,date)) = @date
```

Comment: The question is, how do I convert the decimal date (12-13 chars long) to a date format. In the example, the year also moves to the front of the date.

Comment: Please note that attempting to convert a numeric field directly to a date field will result in unanticipated values - DB2 considers numeric input to be the _number of days_ (-1) since 0001-01-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see:  You want some way of rearranging the digits of a number to become a date.  It looks like the encoding is `[m]mddyyyy`.  (Why isn't that a `date` datatype in the database?)

The number needs to be converted to a string and then substrings arranged and converted to a date.  Given the complexities here, a conversion function should be written in lieu of the field being altered to be a proper datatype.  Something like this should do it (untested, no access to db2):

```
create function decimaldate(decdate DECIMAL) 
returns DATE
return
with tmp (dstr) as
(
    select substr(digits (decdate),8)
    from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
select
  date (substr(dstr,4,4) || '-' ||
        substr(dstr,1,2) || '-' ||
        substr(dstr,3,2)
       )
from tmp
```

This converts the number to a string, reformats the string as `yyyy-mm-dd` and converts to a date.  (I used [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html) as a basis.)

So the solution to the original question is simply to write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE decimaldate(DECIMALCOLUMN) = @date
```

With such a screwy way of encoding the date in the database, having the function always available should prove invaluable.

Comment: That is perfect. You are right. Thank you. Only problem is I only have select access. I cant create a function in the db. Is there still someway to select your code?

Comment: @user719825:  Try this:  `WHERE date (substr(digits(DECIMALCOLUMN),4,4) || '-' || substr(digits(DECIMALCOLUMN),1,2) || '-' || substr(digits(DECIMALCOLUMN),3,2)) = @date`.  Yucky, but functionally equivalent.  If there is any problem, try displaying the expression and `decimalcolumn` to see what might be wrong.