# Change datatable (from AS400) column format

Tags: .net, oledb, ibm-midrange

I'm having this issue:

Our AS400 keeps dates as **Decimal** in format *yyyyMMdd* but when
I need them in our software they should be **DateTime** in format *ddMMyyy*

How do I best go about getting the right format and type?
I looked at IBM website for setting the Format at connection...
But it seems you need to have your date in a DateTime type of column to start with to be able
to set a format.

**http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Frzaikconnstrkeywordsformatprop.htm**

I also tried cloning the datatable and setting the appropriate columns to the correct datatype but then I need to loop all rows and each cell to convert which is next to
impossible to do on large queries.

Can anybody help me out?

This is the code I used to change the datefields doing the query:

```
' convert date for selects
        If type = Operation.SelectMultipleRows Or type = Operation.SelectSingleValue Then

            For Each s As String In _datefields
                sql = sql.Replace(s, "REPLACE(CHAR(DATE(SUBSTR(CHAR(" & s & "), 1, 4) ||'-'|| SUBSTR(CHAR(" & s & "), 5, 2) ||'-'|| SUBSTR(CHAR(" & s & "), 7, 2)),EUR),'.','/') as " & s)
            Next

        End If
```

The above only works if requested fields are given in select query. If you use * then it simply does not work.

In iSeries AS400 you can get a list of all the column names if you know the tablename but I can't rely on it because the query passed could contain joins, ....

Example:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM QSYS2/COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580956/convert-db2-sql-decimal-to-date

Comment: What is it about the catalog view COLUMNS that you "can't rely on"?  What is the issue?  Or what is the problem set you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an actual date data type available on DB2 for IBM i.  There are some older databases which still use a decimal number rather than a date data type, which is the situation you have.

If the IBM admin will let you load software onto the i, try Alan Campin's [iDate service program](http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm).  It will give you a set of user defined functions that will perform decimal to date conversions so that you can use fairly simple SQL statements to manipulate these numeric data types.

If you can't load software onto the IBM side, you will be forced to do the conversions yourself through some ugly variant of:

```
date(
     substr(char(numericDate),1,4) concat 
     '-' concat 
     substr (char(numericDate),5,2) concat 
     '-' concat 
     substr(char(numericDate),7,2)
  )
```

This contortion is needed because the DATE() function requires a character field in ISO format.

Comment: Thank you very much Buck, I will research the above with our AS400 Architect to see if this is possible to implement. I am aware how to transform decimal to date field but it's just a problem of interfacing a general functon that takes any sql and a given set of datefields to change only those. I will mark this as an answer but any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @JamesA's suggestion about creating a view is an excellent one.

Comment: Using a UDF will still require explicit field declaration in the query or view.

Comment: Yes.  Didn't realise that OP was limited to SELECT *

Comment: I think you want `digits()` in your answer, rather than `char()`.  `digits()` will always return a string with the number of digits in the field, but `char()` will drop any leading zeros, thus messing with the substring positions.

Answer (score 3):

Request a reformatted date in your field selections:

```
date(substr(datefield,1,4) || '-' || substr(datefield,5,2)|| '-' || substr(datefield,7,2)) as datefield
```

Comment: Did that before but can't use that if querying * fields.

Comment: @grmbl It's better to use explicit field selections on queries instead of `*`.

Comment: Maybe if I could query the datatable with Linq? Afraid I don't know enough Linq though...

Comment: agreed but some tables have over 150 fields and we need all of them... :P

Comment: @grmbl Your only other option is to create views over the tables mapping the fields as required or handle the conversion within your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't download or use the SQL functions mentioned in @Buck's answer, or , I recommend that you (or someone) create an SQL User Defined Function in the database.

Make it a `DETERMINISTIC` function, which means that the results will the same whenever the input to the function is the same.  This allows DB2 to cache the results, which will give you better performance, since it won't have to repeat the calculation each and every time it sees the same value again.

Perhaps something along the lines of this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION YMD2DATE (ymd dec(8,0) )
                        returns  date
       SPECIFIC YMD2DATE_dec8
       LANGUAGE SQL
       CONTAINS SQL
       DETERMINISTIC
       NO EXTERNAL ACTION
       RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
       NOT FENCED
       SET OPTION DBGVIEW = *SOURCE
prc:       BEGIN NOT ATOMIC  -- not atomic means dont rollback on error
             DECLARE ans    date    default '0001-01-01';
             SET     ans = date( insert(insert( trim(digits(ymd)) ,7,1,'-'),5,1,'-'))  );
             RETURN  ans;
           END prc
;
```